# SubView only showing for the first time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am building an iOS app using Swift 3, which shows a `UITableView` as subview when I click on a `UITextField` for selecting items. When I select items, I execute this code in `table​View(_: did​Select​Row​At:​)` function

```
    self.view.viewWithTag(104)?.removeFromSuperview()
```

After this when I click the `UITextField` again, the subview is showing up again.

To show the subview, I have written this code in `viewDidLoad()` function

```
self.textFieldGetCountry.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.createActionSheet), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin)
```

How do I show the subview again ?

Comment: hide it instead?

Comment: Thank you all guys for answering my question . I realize i just didn't add
self.textFieldChoosCountry.resignFirstResponder() in my table​View(_: did​Select​Row​At:​) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
/* Create a lazy property */
lazy var customView: UIView = {
    let view = // init your view
    /* configuration (frame, color etc.)... */
    return view
}()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /* Add your subview to viewControllers view */
    self.view.addSubview(customView)
}


/* Make a function that regulates your view's hide/unhide propery or alpha */
func showCustomView(show: Bool) {
    customView.alpha = show ? 1.0 : 0.0
    /* alternative */
    // customView.isHidden = !show
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `hide/show` the `tableView` because if you remove it from the superview, then you need to add it also when `textField` become the first responder.

```
//Show the tableView in createActionSheet
func createActionSheet() {
    self.view.viewWithTag(104)?.isHidden = false
}

//Hide the tableView didSelectRow
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.isHidden = true
}
```

It is batter if you create the `IBOutlet` of `tableView` so it is easy to access it.

Comment: when i use isHidden it only hides items of the table view not the whole table view.

Comment: @MituVinci Can you show the screenshot of issue issue you are talking about because if you hide tableView it will hide all its contains like sectionHeader,footer cell all of this will be hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subView using the following code snippet in the `createActionSheet()` function

```
self.view.addSubview(UIView)
```

Happy Coding.